# smooth scroll with waypoints jquery(animation)

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-animate, smooth-scrolling

I'm trying to make a smooth scrolling in my new website.

Look at this site: http://asher-gallery.com/

There is 3 blocks that I want to link to "a href=#(.*)" that I could make smooth scroll same like that: http://asher-gallery.com/1/.

I change the parameters and its moving to the block location but not with animate...

I hope you guys may help me with this !

THX!

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work if you wrap it in a click event

```
$("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: $('#element-to-scroll-to').offset().top }, 300);
```

Comment: `code
$("a.1").click(function(){
  $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: $('#gallery').offset().top }, 800);
 });
`
nothing happen, I have created "a.1" and the element - #element-to-scroll-to : "#gallery" is exist. nothing happen..

Comment: You need to prevent default on the link so it doesnt direct to the same page. Try this. $("a.1").click(function( e ){ $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: $('#gallery').offset().top }, 800); e.preventDefault(); });

Comment: Hi, sorry for the late reply. Could you console.log the value of $('#gallery').offset().top and tell me what it is?

Comment: I have did that, he get me the value =  -111.

Comment: That should return a positive number. Im not sure what else to suggest. Is there only one element with an id of gallery on the page?

Comment: i was on something, http://asher-gallery.com/try.
when you scroll the page the number is change.
the clear value is 60.

Answer (score 0):

CSS classes can not start with numbers, if your class is like *class="1"*, the code is ignoring.